# Lightouse PHP Graphql - How to create a relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm struggling to understand how to create relationships through lighthouse.  Let's say I have a `Post` model that `belongsTo` a `User`. In my `schema.graphql`, I have:

```
type Mutation {
  createPost(input: CreatePostInput! @spread): Post! @create
}

input CreatePostInput! {
  text: String!
  user: BelongsToUser!
}

input BelongsToUser {
  connect: ID!
}
```

And my Post object in the database has a foreign key column of `user_id`

When I run the query:

```
mutation {
  createPost(input: {
    text: "Hello World",
    user: {
      connect: 1
    }
  }){
    id
  }
}
```

I get an error: `Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`

I feel like I am doing something wrong where this mutation is not updating the correct column for the relationship, can someone please point me to what I might be doing wrong? *(If I make the column nullable with a default value in the database, it is inserted but the relationship is of course incorrect. I can also adjust the graphql schema to use `user_id: Int` which does work but feels like the wrong way to do things.)*

Everything works correctly via Eloquent, and graphql queries work, correctly pulling in related objects.

Note: As per [the documentation](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#return-types-required), I have defined the return class of the relationship in my model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

and the relevant migration:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
  $table->string('text');
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but are using a right Keys ? 
In php my admin go to designer section and select the relation 
if you got will get more clear error 
to know more about designer follow this link 
https://kb.bodhost.com/turn-the-designer-mode-on-in-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that although the return type was defined in the model, I failed to import it above:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    ...
```

‍♂️